# É incorreto afirmar que em uma estrutura de dados do tipo pilha, o elemento que será removido da estrutura é aquele que está armazenado no cabeçalho?

Tags: terminologia, estrutura-de-dados, stack

Em uma prova de estrutura de dados tive a seguinte questão:

> Em uma estrutura de dados do tipo pilha, o elemento que será removido
>   da estrutura é aquele que está armazenado
>
> a) há mais tempo.
>
> b) há menos tempo.
>
> c) na base da estrutura.
>
> d) no cabeçalho da estrutura.
>
> e) no centro da estrutura.

Na hora de responder fiquei em dúvida entre:

b) há menos tempo.

d) no cabeçalho da estrutura.

Principalmente porque as vi como sendo equivalentes, o elemento que está armazenado a menos tempo está armazenado no topo da estrutura, o que seria equivalente ao cabeçalho, certo?

Assim, é incorreto afirmar que em uma estrutura de dados do tipo pilha, o elemento que será removido da estrutura é aquele que está armazenado no cabeçalho da pilha?

Comment: Eu acredito que nem sempre é verdadeira, pois visto quando a pilha é implementada com uma lista encadeada, o cabeçalho estará apontando para o início da lista, não necessariamente para o último elemento da pilha. Só não tenho certeza se é realmente isso, posso estar enganado sobre o conceito de cabeçalho.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss é até possível implementar uma pilha como um lista ligada, mas não é uma boa ideia. Não há vantagens para a pilha ter esse encadeamento. O encadeamento não resolve um problema existente. Há desvantagens de consumo de memória e processamento. A melhor forma de implementar uma pilha é com um *array* simples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Precisaria definir o que é cabeçalho. Uma pilha não tem cabeçalho. Então ou está falando de outra coisa nessa hipotética resposta ou está usando o termo de uma forma não usual, pelo menos pra mim.

Eu acho que sequer está falando de pilha na opção d.

A única que faz sentido é a b.